# Play mp3 songs from SDcard

Tags: android

I am accessing songs from sdcard in android, songs are displayed in ListView, but i can't play those files.

here is the code:

```
package com.ex.imageGallery;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;

public class temp extends Activity{
      protected static final String TAG = null;
    private Cursor audioCursor;
      private int video_column_index;
      private static String currentposition;
      ListView videolist;
      int count;

      /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.list_audio);
            //init_phone_video_grid();
            System.gc();
            final String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
  MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
  MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
  MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE };

        audioCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,proj, null, null, null);
        count = audioCursor.getCount();
        videolist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneVideoList);
        videolist.setAdapter(new AudioAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
        videolist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                //System.out.println(proj[0]);
                System.out.println(audioCursor.getString(position));
                //Uri mur = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI+Uri.parse(audioCursor.getString(position));
                try{
                MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
                mp.setDataSource(audioCursor.getString(position));
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }


            }



        });
  }

  class AudioAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
      private Context vContext;

      public AudioAdapter(Context c) {
            vContext = c;
      }

      public int getCount() {
            return count;
      }

      public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
      }

      public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
      }

      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            System.gc();
            TextView tv = new TextView(vContext.getApplicationContext());
            String id = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                  video_column_index = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                  audioCursor.moveToPosition(position);
                  id = audioCursor.getString(video_column_index);
                  video_column_index = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE);
                  audioCursor.moveToPosition(position);
                  id += "Size(KB):" + audioCursor.getString(video_column_index);
                  tv.setText(id);
            } else
                  tv = (TextView) convertView;
            return tv;
      }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should also be useful: http://knightswhocode.com/wordpress/2011/02/android-read-file-from-sdcard/

Answer (score 2):

Answer is already accepted, but this is what you're actually looking for:

http://androidsamples.blogspot.com/2009/06/displaying-list-of-music-files-stored.html

Comment: not opening the website

Answer (score 0):

Add this class to your code...

```
public class SongsManager {
    // SDCard Path
    String MEDIA_PATH = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());

    private final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    public SongsManager() {

    }

    public SongsManager(String foldername) {

        MEDIA_PATH =  MEDIA_PATH + foldername +"/";
    }

    /**
     * Function to read all mp3 files from sdcard and store the details in
     * ArrayList
     * */
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList() {
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

        if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
                HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
                song.put(
                        "songTitle",
                        file.getName().substring(0,
                                (file.getName().length() - 4)));
                song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

                // Adding each song to SongList
                songsList.add(song);
            }
        }
        // return songs list array
        return songsList;
    }

    /**
     * Class to filter files which are having .mp3 extension
     * */
    class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3"));
        }
    }
}
```

Create an instantce of this class and read them as..

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        SongsManager plm = new SongsManager();
        // get all songs from sdcard
        this.songsList = plm.getPlayList();

        // looping through playlist
        for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(i);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsListData.add(song);
        }
```

Play a song like this...

```
public void  playSong(int songIndex){
        // Play song
        try {
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
            // Displaying Song title
            String songTitle = songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");
            songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);

            // Changing Button Image to pause image
            btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);

            // set Progress bar values
            songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
            songProgressBar.setMax(100);

            // Updating progress bar
            updateProgressBar();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```